# Sending messages or datas with bluetooth via python

Tags: python, bluetooth

How can i send messages  over bluetooth via python without key authentification like type numbers ?

i used pybluez
but i got this error:

```
File "./send", line 12, in <module>
    connect()
File "./send", line 8, in connect
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
File "<string>", line 5, in connect
    bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import bluetooth

def connect ():
    bd_addr = "x:x:x:x:x:x"
    port = 1
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
    sock.send("hello!!")
    sock.close()

connect()
```

Comment: Please edit with the full error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @TJD said, you need to ensure you bind with the correct port for the service you want.

```
>>> from bluetooth import *
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> devices = discover_devices()
>>> devices
['xx:yy:tt:zz:44:BD', '00:yy:72:zz:bb:aa']
```

Then as the second step try to find the service on the device you want to connect to.

```
>>> service = find_service(address='00:yy:72:zz:bb:aa')
>>> pprint(service)
[{'description': None,
  'host': '00:yy:72:zz:bb:aa',
  'name': 'Headset Audio Gateway',
  'port': 12,
  'profiles': [('1108', 258)],
  ...},
 {'description': None,
  'host': '00:yy:72:zz:bb:aa',
  'name': 'Dial-Up Networking',
  'port': 1,
  'profiles': [('1103', 256)],
  'protocol': 'RFCOMM',
  ...}]
```

Based on this information you can connect to a service running on a device. According to the service/profile [specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/) you send service specific commands and get back information from the device. E.g. in the list above you see the 'Headset Audio Gateway' and the profile list with the number '1108', which is the short uuid for the service. You can now lookup the commands for this profile and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. After binding the address the error went away.

```
rfcomm bind 0 <address> 1
```

The 0 refers to your bluetooth device. The 1 refers to the port number.
If you're running linux you can run *hciconfig* to the the device number.

Comment: The 0 will bind it to /dev/rfcomm0, a 1 will bind it to /dev/rfcomm1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting with the basic rfcomm-client and rfcomm-server example code from pybluez?

http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-client.py

It's basically what your code is doing, but it uses service discovery to ensure connection to proper port.

Comment: use `pip install pybluez`

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the same code in your question, its working for me, i can send some data and see that the data coming into arduino using its Serial Monitor.

But, I did one step prior to it, I paired the HC-05 first with my device (the one using which i am trying to send data, in my case, its a linux machine)

I used bluetoothctl tool to pair .

1. sudo bluetoothctl  # this will start the tool in cli
2. scan on  # this will show the MAC address of hc-05
3. pair <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_HC-05> #this will ask for username and password
4. for my module the password is 1234

[working picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moogV.png)