# python: bluetootherror: (111, 'connection refused')

Tags: python, bluetooth

Hi everyone!

There seems to be a problem with connecting the cellphone to the raspberry pi 3 via Bluetooth. 
I think have a problem with my code.

Here is my code

```
import bluetooth

from bluetooth import  *

serverMAC = 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'

port = 1

s = blutooth.BluetoothScocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

s.connnect((serverMAC, port)
```

I would like to receive the value from the cell phone to Raspberry Pi.

```
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying the code below, make sure the BT adapter on your script-running device is turned on and the target Bluetooth Device is in Discoverable mode (it's adapter is turned on and it's broadcasting capabilities on discovery).

Make sure you use the correct port for the target device. You can do that by running a discover on your available devices, then matching your MAC to one of the found devices and issuing a find_service on the address. Source:[Sending messages or datas with bluetooth via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485750/sending-messages-or-datas-with-bluetooth-via-python)

Tried this on a local machine, mind the MACs will change, so will the profiles, so if you want RFCOMM make sure your device exposes it before trying to connect:

```
from bluetooth import *
devices = discover_devices()
for device in devices:
    print([_ for _ in find_service(address=device) if 'RFCOMM' in _['protocol'] ])
# now manually select the desired device or hardcode its name/mac whatever in the script
bt_addr = ...
port = [_ for _ in find_service(address=bt_addr) if 'RFCOMM' in _['protocol']][0]['port']
s = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
s.connect((bt_addr, port))
```